# How do I import email from another email account into my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, import

I have an email account with a provider other than Gmail and want to import that email into Gmail.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google has a [help page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56283) on this topic, which will allow you to get emails which still exist on the server of your other account (or emails that you receive in the future).

If you want to import email which you have already downloaded (e.g. from a POP3 server), the easiest way by far is to log in to Gmail using the IMAP interface from your email client, and then drag all your old emails into your Gmail inbox.

Comment: The second paragraph was the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is.

In **settings->Accounts and Import->Import mail and contacts** you can import all contacts and received mail from a pop3 or webmail account.

In **settings->Accounts and Import->Add Pop3 email account** you can make gmail to check an account regularly for a mail and get it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is, if the other mail service supports POP3 or IMAP, to use the IMAP feature of Gmail and a third-party mail client.

I did exactly this a long time ago with Thunderbird. I had all my old e-mail in there already and just dragged it to folders that were syncing to Gmail with IMAP.

Comment: This was the simplest to do when switching mail hosts from Zoho to gmail. Exported all mail to zip from Zoho, added my email (now managed by Gmail) to Outlook, and drag & dropped. All emails were then synced to Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

If your "other" e-mail provider allows you to forward e-mail, you can set it up to forward everything to your gmail account.

If the "other" e-mail provider has a POP3 server, you can tell gmail to grab mail from that account. To do so:

1. Start gmail and click the Settings button
2. Select the Accounts and Import tab
3. Click the Add POP3 email account button
4. Fill out the information in the "wizard" that appears

Answer (score 1):

For those of you importing from Yahoo:

Gmail imap method only picks up emails in the inbox folder. If you have subfolder, and wish to move them, you'll have to move them to the inbox. That said, Yahoo doesn't allow you to mass select over 200, which when you have 10k messages, it would suck.

The alternative I came up with was to do a search in Yahoo and select the found messages. by doing that, Yahoo allows to to select all found messages, even if it finds thousands.

You can also further filter your search by date, folders, etc and select/move that way.

Edit:

Note that the trick is just to click on the box rather then on the little arrow and "all"

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com), which is basically Gmail for custom domains like [john@company.com](https://company.com), the admin can migrate emails from your old email server to Gmail:

1. As admin, go to [admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com).
2. Click the "Data Migrations" tile (see image below).
3. Follow the instructions for connecting to the old server.
4. Choose the G Suite user to import emails to.
5. Keep refreshing the page until the loading bar has completed (see second image).

[image]
[image]