# How can I forward email from an old account to my new Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, yahoo-mail, email-forwarding

I have an old Yahoo Mail account on which I still get a few emails, now and then - but I now primarily use Gmail.

Is there a way for me automatically to forward or fetch emails from that account so that they show up in Gmail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import email from another email account into my Gmail account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/207/how-do-i-import-email-from-another-email-account-into-my-gmail-account)

Comment: No, importing email is different from forwarding it...

Comment: It seems Yahoo! Mail Plus is not possible to buy anymore.  I used to forward my mail with and at some point even without Yahoo! Mail Plus.  Now I cannot even figure out how to do it with a paid Ad-free account (as far as I can tell the only paid Yahoo! mail account).  I have asked this of Yahoo Uservoice here: https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/210695-yahoo-mail/suggestions/5445616-how-can-i-forward-my-yahoo-mail-to-gmail-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the **previous answers relate to a feature that is only available through the Yahoo Mail Plus plan, which now costs money**.

If you're willing to pay for Yahoo Mail Plus, which would run you $20 for one year, setting up POP or forwarding, as described in the previous answers, is the way to go.

However, I don't recommend it, as you would be paying for an account you don't really use (and for features that are free in Gmail).

**Instead, you can use the `Import mail and contacts` feature from Gmail**. To set it up, go to `Settings --> Accounts and Import --> Import mail and contacts`.

Comment: This solution would not retrieve the email as the original question asks.

Answer (score 2):

In gmail, you can configure it to retrieve email from another account via pop.

Go to settings, Accounts & Import, and add the details under the "Check Mail using Pop3".  It will automatically label retrieved mail with the name of the account, or you can set up a custom label if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

In Yahoo mail, go to Options -> More options -> POP & Forwarding. Then click on Forward your Yahoo!Xtra Mail and enter your new Gmail address to forward them to. Just click Save Changes at the top and you'll be good to go! [Yahoo's help page](http://help.yahoo.com/l/nz/yahooxtra/mail/yahoomail/mailplus/forwarding/) on it might also be useful

Comment: I believe this feature requires "YAHOO! MAIL PLUS".   It is not possible to POP or forward mail from the free version.

Comment: I don't pay for Yahoo Mail, in fact I don't even use it - I just have a log on from about 10 years ago that still seems to work. The option is definitely there for me, but I can't vouch for whether it works or not.